# Page is not redirecting to URL?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, ion-auth

I'm working on `PHP-CodeIgniter` project. I'm using `ION Auth library` for authentication.

My question is when I'm copy paste table data to Excel sheet, and then click on links copied to excel are `not properly redirect` to particular page. If I `hover mouse on the link it shows proper address`, but while clicking on it then it `redirects to Dashboard` not to `particular page`, their is a `Active session data`, but it redirects to Dashboard only.

**Controller code:**

```
<?php (defined('BASEPATH')) OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Auth extends CI_Controller
{

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    // $this->load->library('');
    $this->load->model('Landlord_m', 'l');

}

public function index()
{
    redirect('auth/login');
}

public function login()
{
    if( $this->ion_auth->logged_in() ) redirect('dashboard');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'email', 'required|valid_email|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'password', 'required|trim');

    $this->form_validation->set_message('required', 'Please enter your %s');

    //  Validate form
    if( $this->form_validation->run() )
    {
        $remember   =   (bool) $this->input->post('remember');

        //  Check login
        if( $this->ion_auth->login($this->input->post('email'), $this->input->post('password'), $remember) )
        {
            //  Login was successful
            redirect('dashboard', 'refresh');
        }
        else
        {
            //  Login was un-successful
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $this->ion_auth->errors());
            redirect('auth/login', 'refresh');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $data['message']    =   $this->session->flashdata('message');

        $this->load->view('auth/login', $data);
    }
}

public function logout()
{
    if( $this->ion_auth->logout() )
        redirect('auth/login');
    else
        die("There was an error logging you out");
}
```

Any kind of help is welcome, Thanks in advance.

Comment: pls show your code

Comment: Where in that code are you redirecting to a "_particular page_"?

Comment: When I'm clicking on link from Excel sheet, it checks 'auth/login' and then redirect to Dashboard. But if I copy paste it then it will redirect to particular page.